# Connect Source endpoints to a Targetdiv in jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I'm trying to connect a sourceEndpoint to a target div. 
This is my addEndpoint

```
var anEndpointSource = {
            endpoint: "Dot",
            cssClass:"endpoint-source",
            paintStyle: {
                strokeStyle: "#FF0AAC",
                fillStyle: "transparent",
                radius: 7,
                lineWidth: 3
            },
            connector: connector,
            connectorStyle: connectorPaintStyle,
            connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle,
            hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle,
            connectorOverlays: overlays,
            isSource: true,
            isTarget: false,
            maxConnections: -1,
            anchor:["Bottom"]
        };

jsPlumb.addEndpoint(parentnode1, { uuid: parentnode1.attr('id')+'_Bottom'}, anEndpointSource);

var id = parentnode1.attr('id');
jsPlumb.makeTarget(id, {
            anchor: 'Continuous',
            allowLoopback:false
        });

function connectNodes(connection) {
        var connection2block = jsPlumb.connect({
            source:connection.sourceId,
            target:connection.targetId,
            anchor:"Continuous",
        });
    }
```

It works fine if I manually make a connection by dragging a connection from source endPoint to a target div. The problem occurs when I try to connect via the jsPLumb.connect(); function.

This is what I want (This happens when I connect manually):
[image]

and This is what I'm getting (This happens if I connect via .connect() funciton):

[image]

As You can see that the connection are not originating form the source endpoint.

I even tried:

```
function connectNodes(connection) {
        var connection2block = jsPlumb.connect({
            source:connection.sourceId+'_Bottom',
            target:connection.targetId,
            anchor:"Continuous",
        });
    }
```

but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successfully able to connect a sourceEndpoint to a target div. Here's the solution:

```
 function connectNodes(connection) {
    var connection2block = jsPlumb.connect({
        uuids: [connection.sourceId+"_Bottom"],
        target:connection.targetId,
        anchor:"Continuous",
    });
}
```